# How JSON parsing of object on Android

Tags: android, json, android-cardview

I am having some problems pulling values from a JSON. I was trying some methods like GSON and Retrofit but I could not do.

I am trying to get the list but I can just get them in a String.

Following the JSON String, I am using

```
{
"1":{
    "ID":"1",
    "about_event":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquam vestibulum urna sed pretium. Mauris pretium vestibulum leo. Donec vel condimentum arcu. Vivamus pharetra lacinia lacus. Pellentesque tempus ullamcorper laoreet. Nunc finibus ex eget felis tincidunt faucibus. Pellentesque non elementum arcu, sit amet lobortis risus.",
    "address":"xasda",
    "category":"A",
    "event_name":"dsfgdsfg",
    "img_url":"url.jpeg",
    "start_date":"324",
    "website":"http"
},
"2":{
    "ID":"2",
    "about_event":"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Integer aliquam vestibulum urna sed pretium. Mauris pretium vestibulum leo. Donec vel condimentum arcu. Vivamus pharetra lacinia lacus. Pellentesque tempus ullamcorper laoreet. Nunc finibus ex eget felis tincidunt faucibus. Pellentesque non elementum arcu, sit amet lobortis risus.",
    "address":"xasda",
    "category":"A",
    "event_name":"Veldhuis & Kemper - Geloof ons nou maar",
    "img_url":"link.jpeg",
    "start_date":"234",
    "website":"https://"
  } 
}
```

I am trying to:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

RecyclerView recyclerView;
EventAdapter eventAdapter;

private RequestQueue requestQueue;
List<Event> eventList;

// JSON data url
private final static String Jsonurl = "x";

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    eventList = new ArrayList<>();
  fetchPosts();

}


private void fetchPosts() {
    StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET, Jsonurl, onPostsLoaded, onPostsError);
    requestQueue.add(request);
}

private final Response.Listener<String> onPostsLoaded = new Response.Listener<String>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(String response) {

        Log.i(Event.class.getSimpleName(), response);
        //how can i fill the list?
        eventAdapter = new EventAdapter(getApplicationContext(), eventList);

        recyclerView.setAdapter(eventAdapter);

    }
};

private final Response.ErrorListener onPostsError = new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e(Event.class.getSimpleName(), error.toString());
    }
};
}
```

What am I missing to do that? or Can you tell me the simplest way to parse the JSON data show it in the `Cardview`?

Comment: You should fill the `eventList` in your `onResponse` method

Answer (score 1):

you can try using **GSON** just passing the raw json string and will return the list of model

```
 public List<SampleModel> getListFromJsonString(String rawJson) {
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    JsonObject object = new JsonParser().parse(rawJson).getAsJsonObject();
    List<SampleModel> sampleModelList = new ArrayList<>();
    for (Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> elementMap : object.entrySet()) {
        JsonObject inner = elementMap.getValue().getAsJsonObject();
        SampleModel sampleModel = gson.fromJson(inner, SampleModel.class);
        sampleModelList.add(sampleModel);
    }
    return sampleModelList;
}
```

and your **SampleModel** should look something like this

```
    public class SampleModel {
    @SerializedName("ID")
    @Expose
    private String iD;
    @SerializedName("about_event")
    @Expose
    private String aboutEvent;
    @SerializedName("address")
    @Expose
    private String address;
    @SerializedName("category")
    @Expose
    private String category;
    @SerializedName("event_name")
    @Expose
    private String eventName;
    @SerializedName("img_url")
    @Expose
    private String imgUrl;
    @SerializedName("start_date")
    @Expose
    private String startDate;
    @SerializedName("website")
    @Expose
    private String website;

    public String getiD() {
        return iD;
    }

    public void setiD(String iD) {
        this.iD = iD;
    }

    public String getAboutEvent() {
        return aboutEvent;
    }

    public void setAboutEvent(String aboutEvent) {
        this.aboutEvent = aboutEvent;
    }

    public String getAddress() {
        return address;
    }

    public void setAddress(String address) {
        this.address = address;
    }

    public String getCategory() {
        return category;
    }

    public void setCategory(String category) {
        this.category = category;
    }

    public String getEventName() {
        return eventName;
    }

    public void setEventName(String eventName) {
        this.eventName = eventName;
    }

    public String getImgUrl() {
        return imgUrl;
    }

    public void setImgUrl(String imgUrl) {
        this.imgUrl = imgUrl;
    }

    public String getStartDate() {
        return startDate;
    }

    public void setStartDate(String startDate) {
        this.startDate = startDate;
    }

    public String getWebsite() {
        return website;
    }

    public void setWebsite(String website) {
        this.website = website;
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you for the helping. i just tried but the error is now: 
Caused by: com.google.gson.stream.MalformedJsonException: Use JsonReader.setLenient(true) to accept malformed JSON at line 1 column 7 path

Comment: it should not be as i have tried the same and it's working fine for me giving the size of two make sure when trying you have the exact json structure what you have mentioned in the question if not then get that particular json object which has above json and then pass to the function.